# Create an almost sorted array

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting

I want to create an "almost sorted" array, as efficiently as possible (to explore effect of random subtle variations in a list, I expect to call this routine a lot).

I have Ruby code which does what I want:

```
sortme = [ 'X','A','B','W','S','J','7','9','Q','E' ]
n = sortme.length

correctly_sorted = sortme.sort
# ["7", "9", "A", "B", "E", "J", "Q", "S", "W", "X"]

# Specific to this case, I'd like the disorder to be strongest at the
# start of the array. In general, I would like to be able to control
# it, in relation to the sorted positions.
sort_adjust = Array.new( n ) { |i| i + ( rand() * 50 ) / (i+10) }

adjust_indexes = (0...n).sort_by { |i| sort_adjust[i] }
# e.g. [0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]

almost_sorted = adjust_indexes.map { |i| correctly_sorted[i] }

# Example output
# ["7", "A", "9", "B", "E", "J", "Q", "S", "X", "W"]
```

My solution performs two `sort`s, a `map`, and calls `rand()` N times to fill a temp array. Is there any way I could reduce number of method calls to `Array`, and make this more efficient? Or perhaps reduce the number of times I call `rand()` but still get a controllable shuffling of items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about applying the standard and efficient [array shuffling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), but adding randomization to it?

The basic algorithm chooses for each position i a random position n>=j>=i to swap values with. Instead, decide to do the swap with a probability p. For p=1 you have the standard shuffling algorithm (where all permutations are equally likely to appear), and for p=0 the array will stay sorted.

Comment: This is my preferred approach. The others are IMO valid and interesting, but I can only tick one.

Answer (score 1):

What a neat question! Here is what occurred to me as a fun solution:

Take your sorted array, and feed it into a graph. The graph should be "mostly" linear, but occasionally insert some branches. That is, flip coins as you traverse the array and when you hit a given threshold, instead of inserting the value in the list and moving forward, you insert the value in the list but stay in place.

```
["7", "9", "A", "B", "E", "J", "Q", "S", "W", "X"]
```

becomes, for example

```
     / -- A -- \
7 -- 9         E -- J -- Q -- S -- W -- X
     \ -- B -- /
```

(when we hit 9, we skipped advancing through the list once. If we had skipped it thrice, we would have ended up with A, B, and E being on the same "level")

Then, to get your "sort-of-sorted" array, you perform a [topological sort](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55891/algorithm-to-sort-based-on-a-partial-order) on the graph! Huzzah!

Comment: In terms of efficiency: you have 1 sort, one O(n) graph construction, and then as many O(n) topological sorts as your heart desires.

Comment: This looks interesting. A secondary property on my wish list is a way to somehow enumerate almost-sorted arrays, with at least some similar results having close enumerations. I think this might get me close to that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, taking into account 2 things:

1. Ruby is quiet fast in sorting.
2. Part of your array is sorted and you don't care about other part of array.

I would split array into 2/3 parts, sort one part, and concatenate parts into one array.

arr2.sort! # sort in place, almost the same as: `arr2 = arr2.sort`
almost_sorted_array = arr1.concat arr2

```
arr = 10.times.collect {(rand(100))}
# => [43, 87, 42, 65, 59, 35, 90, 43, 21, 28] # 10 random numbers

arr1, arr2 = arr[0..3], arr[4..10] # split array into 2 parts
#=> [[43, 87, 42, 65], [59, 35, 90, 43, 21, 28]]

arr2.sort! # sort in place, almost the same as: `arr2 = arr2.sort`
# => [21, 28, 35, 43, 59, 90] # 2nd part is sorted

almost_sorted_array = arr1.concat arr2 #concatenating 2 arrays
#=> [43, 87, 42, 65, 21, 28, 35, 43, 59, 90]
```

Here is just the example how you can start with. You can make some kind of method split an array into 2 or more parts, sort parts that you want to, and concatenate the results.

#### As for *variations to be close to sorted throughout the array*:

You have array that contains 1000 elements. You can split array into, let's say, 100 parts.
Then you must choice what parts to sort. For example(s - sort, d - don't sort):

> [s,d,s,s,d,s,d,s,d,s,d,s,s,s,d,s,s,s,d,s,s...]

Size of the part, number of the parts and if the parts are sorted affects result.
For small arrays or if you want array to be sorted aside **only a few** elements, this solution isn't good.

Comment: This answers the question title (hence +1, because someone searching for this may find it useful), but has a flaw for me: The array is split too dramatically between a completely random section and a perfectly sorted section. I want the variations to be *close* to sorted throughout the array.

Comment: @NeilSlater Ah, I misread this. Well, see the edit. Other solutions are better, though.

Comment: Thank you for the update - sorry for delay responding - I wasn't notified on SO, probably it expects just `@Neil` or `@Neil Slater` to include the space. I think the approach you suggest is valid, but that I would have finer control and better performance with a modified shuffling algorithm.

Comment: @neil-slater It's probably bug. I was using this little pop-up when you start type `@`. Now I was using `neil-slater`, so I guess it should notify you.